# Are there any past or present plans or proposals to explore Martian lava tubes?

Tags: mars, colonization, lava-tubes

Lava tubes on Mars are the prime target for human or robotic missions. They provide protection from radiation, surface conditions, and are thought to have stable internal temperatures. Lava tubes are also a high value scientific target because if there's life on Mars, it's most likely underground. Exploring lava tubes allows underground exploration without powerful digging or earth moving equipment. Lava tubes could also potentially easily be converted to human habitation by covering the cave walls in a liner and pressurizing the interior.

**Question: Are there any past or present space agency plans to explore lava tubes and if so, what would such a mission look like?**

Comment: A robotic mission into a martian lava tube would be very difficult. Relay stations are needed for data transmission, artificial light may be necessary for pictures, usage of solar energy is impossible. If lava tubes are explored, you know nothing about the underground elsewhere without lava.

Comment: Would be interesting to see a spider wired drone cave crawler for this. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiosity_(rover)

Comment: Some links that may help to create an answer:
General article: https://www.universetoday.com/139021/living_underground_exploring_lava_tubes/
White paper: https://www.lpi.usra.edu/decadal/leag/AndrewWDagaFINAL.pdf
Mission proposal: https://www.lpi.usra.edu/meetings/caves2011/pdf/8028.pdf
A possible robot: https://www.sintef.no/en/latest-news/snake-robots-in-space/
A presentation on lava tube exploration: https://www.nasa.gov/pdf/637136main_Whittaker_Presentation.pdf